# php setlocale misbehaviour

Tags: php, locale

Hello and thank you for any insight/info/tip.

We have one page that sends 2 different emails at once. 
Each email is in different language. 
Almost all email content is from database except a small table that contains day names and numbers.

For each email we use a function to send it. Something like:

```
function sendemail($locale, $var1, $var2, $var3)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale); 
    // build email body text
    //day names are presented like: strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M", $checkDate)
    //send email
}
```

The main page uses these function to send the 2 emails

```
sendemail($locale1, $var1, $var2, $var3);
sendemail($locale2, $var1, $var2, $var3);
```

The problem occurs with the second email only. The day names there are based on first locale and not the second one. So, if the first language is English and the second is French, the second email will have English day names instead of French.

Is there a way to fix this? Or somehow destroy/unset/delete/reset the first locale so the second one applies normally?

We are certain we pass different languages/locales in the function.

We currently use the following locales: `en_EN.UTF8, fr_FR.UTF8, el_GR.UTF8, de_DE.UTF8, it_IT.UTF8, ru_RU.UTF8, zh_CN.UTF8, ko_KR.UTF8, es_ES.UTF8, sr_RS.UTF8`